# using one div to restrict the size of another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two divs, 'content-left' and 'content-right'.  The content-left div can vary in height.  The content-right div has a constant height.

UPDATE:  content-left can not only vary in size, but it can vary in size from minute to minute, depending on what the user does.

I wish to have content-left contain a div scroll-bar.  I dont want the browser-window itself to have a scroll bar.

I want the content of the content-right div to be always visible.   content-right should never scroll off the page.

I came up with the code below, but I think it could be better.

I tested this in firefox and chrome.  Internet Explorer is irrelevant to me.

In essence, I merely "hide" the left div, determine the difference between the top of the right div and the window size, and set the max-height property of the left-div.   The scroll then happens by the overflow:auto

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    processLeftDiv();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    processLeftDiv();
});

function processLeftDiv()   {
        $('#content-left').hide();
        windowHeight = $(window).height() ;
        positionTop = $('#content-right').position().top ;
        $('#content-left').css('max-height', ( windowHeight - ( positionTop + 20 ) ) );
             // the 20 is padding
        $('#content-left').show();
}
</script>

<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">

#header
{
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}

#content-left
{
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background: blue;
    display:none;
}
#content-right
{
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    background: green;
}  

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
              Header
             <p>Header stuff</p>
    </div>

    <div id="body">

        <div id="content-left">
                Content left
          <p>Blah Blah</p>
          <p>Blah Blah</p>
          <p>Blah Blah</p>
     repeated 100 times
          <p>Blah Blah</p>
          <p>Blah Blah</p>
          <p>Blah Blah</p>
          <p>Blah Blah</p>
          <p>Blah Blah</p>
        </div><!--close left div-->

        <div id="content-right">
                Content
            <p>Content stuff</p>
        </div><!--close right div-->

    </div><!--close body div-->

</body>
</html>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: have you tried overflow :scroll on left div?

Comment: Ulmar - sorry i updated the post.  the left-container might open up initially with a thousand lines, and then a second later might be down to two lines.  Or this could happen the other way around.   the left-container is extremely dynamic!

Answer (score 1):

No need to complicate this with javascript, you can use CSS only, much more simple. Here's how you do it:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body{
                border: 0;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                outline: 0;
            }
            .header
            {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100px;
                background: red;
            }
            .wrapper
            {
                position: absolute;
                top: 100px;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
            }
            .content-left
            {
                float: left;
                width: 50%;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: auto;
                background: blue;
            }
            .content-right
            {
                float: left;
                width: 50%;
                height: 100%;
                background: green;
            }  
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <p>Header stuff</p>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="content-left">
                Content left
            </div>
            <div class="content-right">
                Content right
            </div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Just a few tips since you're a newbie:

- always try to use classes instead of ids in your html/css, your life will be much more simple in the long run (ids should only be used if you want to bind some javascript to just one element, no other good reasons imo)
- always use some CSS reset block (I used the most simple one here on body tag). I know this is just an example, but in real applications this is a must. Google it, there are some great ones out there.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using ID's, i find it actually helps me to quickly see an ID and know that I have only used it in one area, or I know that if I modify a class element then I may be affecting another area too

Comment: Thanks Vexter - actually the css/html was a cut/paste from another example (in my defense)   -- i should have mentioned in my post that the left-side container is *HIGHLY* dynamic.  it could start out with two lines, and have thousands of lines a minute later.  and i cannot determine any of this when the page loads.

Comment: This will work with any amount of text/content you pour in it. Maybe you should add an overflow:hidden to be safe from overflow. But other than that is seems to be what you were looking for. If that's the case, feel free to accept my answer ;)